# Wrong display of array cell

Tags: c++, arrays

I have problem with display the cell's content.

```
int *probki= new int[liczbaProbek];
for (int i=0; i<liczbaProbek; i++) probki[i]=rand()%2;
koder *mojKoder=new koder();
int *probki2=new int[liczbaProbek];
for (int i=0; i<liczbaProbek; i++)
{
    int X=mojKoder->koduj(probki[i]);
    cout<<X<< " MOJ X"<<endl;
    probki2[i]=X;
    cout<<probki[i]<<" -> "<<cout<<probki2[i]<<endl;
}
```

The X is integer (like tab). When the function is done then X has normal number but when I display the cell content theres a random numbers (probably address).

http://puu.sh/bNOH9/a99c4b9aca.png

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: this not nearly enough sample code for us to help you

Comment: still can't say for sure, but I imagine you are going out of bounds. How big is `probki`?

Comment: It doesnt metter. It happens for 2 and 1000. The problem is that X after function is done gets normal value (for example 11) and when I write X's content to tab there are some random numbers (probably address). Have you even seen something like that? Probki is a dynamic array which size will could be changed.

Comment: I edited the code. As you can see I do it the same like probki2. in "koduj" function I use binary operations- could it be the problem? It returns correct integer numbers... I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing `cout` to `cout`. This gives you the address of `cout` (I think). Change your output line to this:

```
cout << probki[i] << " -> " << probki2[i] << endl;
```